# Why tcolorbox' segmentation.west point is below the border between the upper and the lower parts?

Tags: tcolorbox

As shown by the following MCE, the `tcolorbox`' `segmentation.west` (and `segmentation.east`) point is below the border between the upper and the lower parts of the box (even in the case of `middle=0mm,boxsep=0mm`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={red,ultra thin}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
  skin=bicolor,
  % middle=0mm,
  % boxsep=0mm,
  overlay={
    \draw (segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);
  },
  ]
The upper part.
\tcblower
The lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why?

Comment: Can you please tell us What is expected according to you ?

Comment: I was expecting `segmentation.west` to be at the same height as the border between the upper and the lower parts of the box. Indeed, the documentation says (currently p. 142) "The skin of a `tcolorbox` is drawn by up to four engines. [...] 3. The segmentation (line) of the box, if there is a lower part; drawn by `/tcb/segmentation engine`". Also, concerning the `bicolor` skin, it says (p. 230) it is "quite similar to the `standard` and `enhanced` skin. But instead of a
segmentation line, the optional lower part of the box is filled with a different color or drawn with a different style."

Comment: Ask differently: in the case of the `bicolor` skin, I wonder what are west and east points of the border between the upper and the lower parts of the box.

Comment: Seems to be caused by `yshift=0.1mm` in `\tcb@drawspec@LR` and `\tcb@drawspec@LS`, added in [v3.0.5](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/commit/8787eb0f236f76efc6039a697116705b063d7c7b#diff-f5f726dc38586afe564f49315a0934608d5790b7ea53ded696631400fdd5919c). Need some more time to understand the related codes and to see if it's necessary/improvable.

Comment: To the "ask differently" question, `([yshift=.1mm]segmentation.west) -- ([yshift=.1mm]segmentation.east)` is a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for this excavation work! :) Strange shift, moreover hard-coded... And, next time, it will be askED differently ;)